# Magento 2 reset sorting not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am working on Magento 2.4. I need some customisation in that I need to reset previous sorting and I need to set new 'Order By' column. I am using `$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);` but it is not working and I am getting following error :

> main.CRITICAL: Error: Class
> 'Vendor\Module\Plugin\Zend_Db_Select' not found in /app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Layer.php:174

How to use reset sort column ? Any solution ?

**UPDATE**

I got the solution for above question and used the following

```
$result_main->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
$result_main->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.entity_id, " . implode(",", $id_order) . ")"));
```

But it is not sorting based on given ids.

I also print the query :

> SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
> `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
> LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price),
> price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`,
> `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM
> `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
> `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON
> price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id
> = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1'  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON
> product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND
> product_website.website_id = 1 **ORDER BY FIELD**(e.entity_id, 2521, 10,
> 4444, 1286, 4396, 4397, 656, 4445, 4307, 3110, 1276, 9, 4446, 1280,
> 1611, 155, 286, 5319, 4395, 4392, 4399, 4401, 6424, 1445, 2967, 1281,
> 1278, 6188, 4398, 4389, 4393, 3167, 4944, 4571, 4388, 4390, 4391,
> 4394, 4950, 4945, 1529, 4400, 1526, 1525, 1523, 4948, 4947, 1527,
> 4306, 4943, 1709, 4372, 4447, 6189, 1444, 3539, 4566, 3534, 3538,
> 3535, 3536, 3537, 5507, 4402, 1524, 1123, 4760, 5777, 5384, 1792,
> 4512, 3374, 4552, 4882, 4538, 4885, 5775, 1578, 6567, 5332, 4368,
> 1561, 1559, 4522, 5968, 6377, 5776, 5778, 1577, 6379, 6466, 6384,
> 5965, 6381, 4508, 4570, 4886, 1793, 4507, 3375, 4521, 4506, 5782,
> 3540, 4880, 1446, 5785, 4540, 4884, 4539, 4883, 5784, 5783, 4547,
> 6398, 6200, 4879, 4881, 4548, 4546, 1809, 5779, 5780, 5786, 4467,
> 5781, 6136, 3508, 3507, 3844, 4858, 4857, 6382, 5034, 4437, 6378,
> 4473, 6383, 6380, 5616, 5619, 5620, 5621, 4468, 6572, 6394, 4365,
> 6479, 4370, 4303, 4511, 4935, 4574, 4517, 4524, 4525, 1565, 1566,
> 1567, 4373, 4513, 4510, 4369, 6140, 4509, 309, 3509, 4471, 4577, 4472,
> 3468, 3469, 4573, 4470, 4366, 1770, 3412, 4526, 4531, 6267, 6471,
> 4533, 4532, 4535, 4534, 6026, 4958, 4939, 4940, 4527, 4720, 4528,
> 4523, 5189, 6559, 1482, 1483, 6201, 6482, 6596, 4519, 1336, 6387,
> 6585, 4576, 4500, 1568, 4520, 4010, 4367, 4376, 4371, 1105, 4374,
> 4572, 3492, 1560, 1562, 6472, 6369, 5573, 4575, 198, 199, 200, 201,
> 1564, 4375, 5265, 6397, 1768, 6598, 4567, 6628, 1810, 1257, 1811,
> 4329, 4514, 4469, 4518, 1000, 3506, 4012, 1253, 1254, 1255, 1256,
> 1258, 1252, 1259, 1260, 1261, 1262, 1263, 1265, 1266, 1267, 1268,
> 1269, 1270, 1558, 6345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using it as described below:

**RESETTING THE ORDER**

```php
$collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
```

---

***ADDING PREDEFINED ORDER TO COLLECTION***

```php
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id, ' . implode(',', $allIds) . ')'));
```

---

***FILTER BY SPECIFIC IDS AND SORT BY IDS***

if you want to limit the collection to include only products with specific IDs, then you should use

```php
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $allIds]);
$collection->setOrder('entity_id', \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

---

***ADDING PREDEFINED ORDER TO COLLECTION AND SORT BY THE SAME COLUMN***

otherwise, if you still need to use the initial approach with the `->order()` method, then try appending the regular order after the above lines of code and see what happens:

```php
$collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id, ' . implode(',', $allIds) . ')'));
$collection->setOrder('entity_id', \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::SQL_ASC);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but after reset I added sorting 
$result_main->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.entity_id, all ids)"));

Comment: and the above is not working it is not sorting based on Id which I passed

Comment: is 'all ids' meant to be an array of IDs? if so, please my updated answer on how to add the order to the collection based on your values.

Comment: Yes I did the same but still not working.
$result_main->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
      $result_main->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.entity_id, " . implode(",", $id_order) . ")"));

Comment: on a second thought, i guess you are actually trying to do something else. when you use `->order()` with a Zend expression like this, you are telling the collection that you want the results ordered in the order provided by the array in the expression. what i think you initially wanted was to **filter** the collection to include only certain IDs and then order it by entity ID. can you confirm? i also updated my answer, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, no I have collection. I want to sort that with particular order by passing id. Example : On magento search page I searched something and I got 3 results. say product id is 2,4,6. then I want to sort that result in particular id like 4,2,6. I am trying this in catalog/model/Layer.php I created plugin and trying on that function but not working.

Comment: Hello Diana for the above issue I created new question can you please look ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/334962/magento-2-sort-collection-in-particular-order-before-display

Comment: hmm I see. this is indeed helpful information. let's see if we can find a solution. i will check the other question and see if i can come up with something.

Comment: If you can guide me to sort with static way it would be great ! I just want to display "normal"(normal-> it is product attribute value) products first then "priority"(priority -> uit is same attribute's other option) product should display.